# Pagination on home page not working

Tags: pagination, 404-error

My problem is [here](http://www.vrati-pazardjik.com/new/). When I press page 2, 3 or other on my HOME page it just goes to 404 not found, but when I go in any category, and press page 2 it works great.

I have tried changing the permalinks without any success. Also turning off and on plugins, deleted .htaccess and remade it with right permissions, cleared cache. This happens only in HOME. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if(get_option('zens_home') == "blog") { ?>  
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/blog-home.php'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>

<div id="featured">

<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php 
        $slide = get_option('zens_slide_cat');
        $count = get_option('zens_slide_count');
        $slide_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=products&product-category='.$slide.'&posts_per_page='.$count.'' );
        while ( $slide_query->have_posts() ) : $slide_query->the_post();
    ?>  
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="slideimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_image_url()?>&amp;h=300&amp;w=500&amp;zc=2" title="" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="flex-caption">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_slide', ''); ?>
            <div class="slidetab">
            <span class="sprice"><?php $price=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fabthemes_price', true); echo $price; ?></span>
            <span class="spdetails"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Още</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
<div id="home-content" class="clearfix">
<ul id="shelf">

    <?php
        $home_count = get_option('zens_home_count');
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$home_count.'&post_type=products'.'&paged='.$paged);
    ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>   

    <li class="box" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php $disc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fabthemes_discount', true); ?>
    <?php if ( $disc ) { ?>
            <span class="salebadge"></span>
    <?php }?>
        <div class="boxtitle">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="productshot" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=200&amp;w=170&amp;zc=2" alt=""/></a>

        <div class="pricetab clearfix">

        <?php if ( $disc ) { ?>
            <span class="oldprice"><del> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fabthemes_disc-price', true) ?> </del></span>
        <?php }?>

        <span class="price"><?php $price=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fabthemes_price', true); echo $price; ?></span>
        <span class="prodetail"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Още</a></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php getpagenavi(); ?>
    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

</ul>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a query on the loop in your theme's index.php.?? Also please share your home page code.

Comment: I am not expert :( , there is the index http://codepad.org/w1saMfv2

Comment: please share index page via question.

Comment: i should start a new question?

Comment: No , just edit this current question and put code and submit.

Comment: it's done, can you check now ? thanks

Comment: done still nothing....

Comment: does that working?

Comment: please add 
$args= array(
'paged' => $paged
);  just after $paged = $page;

Comment: did that also, still nothing changes..

Comment: ok then remove those code which I have told to add. may be some one else can help you.

Comment: thanks for your time! i will wait for someone else then.